# What is the solution to NativeScript "Cannot read property 'match' of null" error after "tns doctor"

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to install **NativeScript** in my machine,
tns CLI was successfully installed, but when i try to execute **tns doctor** commande, I'm getting this error :
[Cannot read property 'match' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CkRx.png)

I'm developing an application for **android** platform, so I don't need to install Xcode.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Do you ahve Android SDK and Java JDK installed. Also are you environment paths set (ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME). On what operating system you are working and with what version f node.js & npm

Comment: Node : v4.4.7
npm : v2.15.8
OS : OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
Yes I've Android and Java JDK installed!

Comment: Perhaps you do not have CocoaPods installed try running "sudo gem install cocoapods"  as suggested here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1245 - after the install of CocoaPods run "pod setup"

Comment: If you do a `tns create test` then `cd test` then `tns platform add android` then finally `tns build android` what happens?

Comment: @Nathanael I have created a new project and run it successfully  on Android, it means that the error above is not blocking the process!

Comment: @AissaBouguern - Yeah, the error you are getting from the doctor is probably an expectation that xcode (& related tooling) would be installed on a mac.  The doctor unfortunately can be wrong when you are doing something outside the ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

If you running mac osx, just install Xcode from Apps Store and run this

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

If it doesn't work, try install CocoaPods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and try again running above code. This problem only occur when running mac. The Nativescript developers might be thinking, if you running mac then you should install Xcode. So if you don't you will get errors for not installing it.